# how to use lodash to find specific result in collection?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am working on lodash ...I want to find particular array if matching id mind in that particular array...This is my collection:-

```
[ { name: 'Thor',
    id: 
     [ '5a1676da509a93571c15501f',
       '59ffb40f62d346204e09c9ad',
       '5a0a92e01bb28a276abfa548' ] },
  { name: 'Loki',
    id: 
     [ '59ffb40f62d346204e09c9ad',
       '59ffb41b62d346204e0a03ed',
       '59ffb40e62d346204e09c298',
       '5a65853af431924e73c401fe' ] } ]
```

What I am trying to find i have given id if it should find it above collection then it should return that collection...for example..if i have id:59ffb40e62d346204e09c298,then it should return 2 collection.....

```
b =  _.find(upperArray,(candidate) => {
            //  console.log(candidate)
           return _.find(candidate.id,id)//here actor_id is given id
            })
```

but it does not return 2 collection.If it does not found any matching element it should return blank array or if found it should return collection of array.Where I am doing wrong??

Comment: If you want to return all matches use `_.filter`, not `_.find`.

Comment: Why should it return 2 collections? That ID only matches `Loki`, not `Thor`.

Comment: but it doesnot return array...https://jsfiddle.net/5pgkqfsf/

Comment: The problem is that `_.find()` doesn't work the way you think it does. `_.find(["a", "b"], "b")` doesn't return anything.

Comment: ok thanks .... i got the point .....i have to return from find also...thanks...:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Barmar is correct you should use `_.filter`. Try the following

```js
var upperArray = [
  {
    name: 'Thor',
    id: [
      '5a1676da509a93571c15501f',
      '59ffb40f62d346204e09c9ad',
      '5a0a92e01bb28a276abfa548'
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Loki',
    id: [
      '59ffb40f62d346204e09c9ad',
      '59ffb41b62d346204e0a03ed',
      '59ffb40e62d346204e09c298',
      '5a65853af431924e73c401fe'
    ]
  }
];

function findById(idToFind) {
  return _.filter(upperArray,function(candidate) {
    return _.includes(candidate.id, idToFind);
  });
}

var b = findById('59ffb40e62d346204e09c298');

console.log(b);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using can achieve the same using native array methods

```js
var id = "59ffb40e62d346204e09c298";
var arr = [{
    name: 'Thor',
    id: ['5a1676da509a93571c15501f',
      '59ffb40f62d346204e09c9ad',
      '5a0a92e01bb28a276abfa548'
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Loki',
    id: ['59ffb40f62d346204e09c9ad',
      '59ffb41b62d346204e0a03ed',
      '59ffb40e62d346204e09c298',
      '5a65853af431924e73c401fe'
    ]
  }
]

function getMatchedCollection(id) {
  // filter will return a new array of matched condition
  return arr.filter(function(item) {
    // indexOf is used to check if an element is present

    if (item.id.indexOf(id) !== -1) {
      return item

    }
  })

}

console.log(getMatchedCollection(id))
```